# Javascript get content of external site after manual (user) login

Tags: javascript, iframe, proxy

YQL would maintain this session data since I believe it is going to the site on it's server and then returning the content to me.
PLEASE HELP.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how it would work because this schedule won't be returned in JSON format but you could have a look at JSONP anyway which is a common workaround to the same-origin policy. Another way it could be done is to make an AJAX call to your OWN server, then from the server get the schedule from your school. Parse the schedule to whatever format you need on your server, and finally return the object back to your AJAX callback function.

Comment: This article here contains both my methods that I stated.
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/JSONToJSONP.aspx

Comment: You could try pass the session cookie to your server perhaps and then request the schedule? I don't know really how you would do that but it's an idea.

Comment: Yeah that was a concept that i considered - have the user log in and then use the session cookie in a PHP cUrl or something... but I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: Perhaps the document.cookie object might be useful to get the cookie returned from the server. I think it will be in your iframe though so you would have to keep it there. make it a json object, send it to your server, make it a cookie, attach to request, get the shcedule, parse the schedule return results?http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

Comment: I happened upon CSSHttpRequest... would this work to get the schedule?